# How to include a barcode font in DOMPDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fonts

I would like to add a barcode font on a label, I generate the label in PDF.

when I generate the label in PDF it does not work but in my view it works fine.

I use [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage) for laravel.

View:
[image]

PDF:
[image]

I include my font like this:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'barcode_fontregular';
        src: url('{{url('/css/barcode/BarcodeFont.ttf')}}') format('woff2'),
             url('{{url('/css/barcode/BarcodeFont.ttf')}}') format('woff');
             url('{{url('/css/barcode/BarcodeFont.ttf')}}') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you put your "css" folder?

Comment: In the root folder of the laravel app @Ronald

Comment: Not in the public folder? If you put it in the public folder I suggest using this {{URL::asset('/css/barcode/BarcodeFont.ttf')}}

Comment: @Ronald Does using the public folder make a diffrence? Since the font is working in the view and the link to the file is correct

Comment: It doesn't make a difference though. Can you check this out https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1208? It seems that you have similar issue.

Comment: It makes difference, because url or asset method is pointing public folder.

Comment: Remeber to always put your files into public folder. Then you can create folders like css, js etc.

Comment: yeah but when i made the .htaccess to strip the /public/ from the URL the css etc didn't work anymore. so i placed the css js etc into the root folder @forexknight

Comment: Yea, the problem is located somewhere else, if everything displays well in your view, so it also should display well in PDF, hmm...

Comment: Ok, I found out how to solve this. You need to apply font family to your document body. Here you have more information https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/About-Fonts-and-Character-Encoding

Comment: @forexknight When i do this the whole document is in barcode in the view, but when the pdf is generated it still doesn't work...

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: @JordyGroote ahhh, just simple typo, it's good that you've solved it out! :)

Comment: @forexknight Coding can be annoying sometimes, thanks for the help mate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

First there was a typo in my style:

```
url('{{url('/css/barcode/BarcodeFont.ttf')}}') format('woff');
url('{{url('/css/barcode/BarcodeFont.ttf')}}') format('truetype');
```

The ; at the first line had to be a comma.

It then gave me a different error pointing to the /storage/fonts not found.

I created the directory and placed my BarcodeFont.ttf in there and it worked.

Thanks alot everybody who tried helping me with this!